# javascript check for valid json

Tags: javascript

I have this if statement looking for a json object:

```
updateStudentData = function(addUpdateData) {
    var rowDataToSave;

    if(addUpdateData.data.row) {
        rowDataToSave = addUpdateData.data.row;
    } else {
        rowDataToSave = addUpdateData.data;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can check to see if the json has a row object?  Currently I get cannot read row property of undefined.

Comment: Just FWIW: That's not a JSON object. It's just an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices:

#### 1. Testing for truthiness

```
if (addUpdateData.data && addUpdateData.data.row) {
```

This would be the most appropriate in your situation, since you're expecting `addUpdateData.data` to be an object reference.

The next two choices are really only needed if the property may have a falsy value like `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or (of course) `false` but you still want to know if the property is there.

#### 2. `hasOwnProperty`

```
if (addUpdateData.hasOwnProperty("data") && addUpdateData.data.row) {
```

This checks to see if `addUpdateData` has an "own" (not inherited) propety called `data`. Not necessary in your case.

#### 3. `in`

```
if ("data" in addUpdateData && addUpdateData.data.row) {
```

This checks to see if `addUpdateData` has a `data` property (either its own, or one it inherits). Not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 4):

you can modify your condition to be `if (addUpdateData.data && adUpdateData.data.row)`

Answer (score -1):

**Try this it will help you :**

```
function isValidJson(jsonData) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(jsonData);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
var jsonstr = '{"name":"xyz","Skill":"Javascript"}'
var res = isValidJson(jsonstr);
console.log(res);
```

Here, we are passing **`JSON String(jsonstr)`** into the function **`isValidJson(jsonstr)`** and then checked if string is JSON parse or not.